# iPhone won't connect to wifi but iPad do

Tags: wifi, iphone

My home network is same and so is the setting, I been using it for months my net connection but today my mother iPhone and my iPhone couldn't connect to home wifi. But my iPad is working fine. I didn't change any setting in iPhone, when I try to connect, it shows busy icon and that's it. 
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because some of the wireless settings have gone wrong. It's hard to tell exactly what went wrong without more information, but you can reset your network settings by the following:

Go to `Settings` > `General` > `Reset Network Settings`.

Then try connecting to your wifi again.

(or you could try turning the iPad off and on again :)

Comment: ᔕᖺᘎᕊ,why turn off the iPad then on ?